# javaScript hoisting not working properly

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

These are 2 examples which must have attained same result:

> **Example 1**

```
<script>
console.log(a);
var a = 10;
console.log(a);
</script>
```

**Rendered**

```
<script>
var a = "";
console.log(a); //will result undefined
a = 10;
console.log(a); //will result 10
</script>
```

**Result**

```
undefined 
10
```

> **Example 2**

```
<script>
console.log(a);
a = 10;
console.log(a);
</script>
```

**Expectation of Rendering**

```
<script>
var a = "";
console.log(a); //should result undefined 
a = 10;
console.log(a); //should result 10
</script>
```

**Result**

[image]

Now, as per JS Hoisting in **Scenario 2**, the variable if not declared must have been automatically declared onto top of its scope and still result should have been the same. Why is it not? Where is the concept failed?

Comment: Where do you get the rendered code information from?

Comment: Just put `var a = 10` and you'll get what you expect. `a = 10` is not the same of `var a = 10`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it

Comment: I wrote how JS must be rendering the code!

Comment: `""` is not undefined.

Comment: OK, @Peterson, because it is wrong :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second case is different, because

```
a = 10
```

... does not declare a hoisted variable. It creates a property in the `window` object (even if the code would have been inside a function). This is not a declaration, and thus something that is *not* hoisted. So before you create that property, it does not exist.

Note that what you listed as *rendered code* is not entirely correct. A hoisted variable does not get a value, so for your first example it should look like this:

```
var a; // undefined!
console.log(a); // will output undefined
a = 10;
console.log(a); // will output 10
```

Note that if this code is not part of a function body, `var a` *also* creates the `window.a` property, and this happens at the hoisted declaration.

And for your second example, the *rendered code* could look like this

```
console.log(a); // Error: does not exist. 
window.a = 10;
console.log(a); // will output 10
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript hoists declarations, not initializations, see [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp).

If you add a 'var a;' somewhere in your second example, it should work fine!

Comment: The first phrase hits the nail on the head. Well put!

Answer (score 1):

On example 2, at the time you run the first console log, `a` is really undefined.

a = 10 sets a new property `a` to the `window` object and there's no 'hoisting' when setting a property to an object that already exists.

Answer (score -1):

when we will execute a source code .IN hoisting, The declaration variable goes over console.log().Then the variable allowcated a memory but does not access it. When I declaration a variable in memory. Then we give by default undefined  value in place of that variable. (as like ,in html,place Holder works like this.
--- So you have not declared any variable. Hosting will not work here.
--- Can't access a here..Because when you define a variable.
Then you must be  defined a variable.here u can not make variable so output: **cannot access a**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).